# failed to download laravel/laravel from dist:

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-9

*Installing laravel/laravel (v10.0.4)
Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Now trying to download from source

- Syncing laravel/laravel (v10.0.4) into cache*

**When ever i want to download laravel using command line i'm getting the above error**

Some how i have installed the laravel latest version of 10.

and trying to run the dev server using **php -S localhost:8080 -t public** then this error arises

*
Warning: require(C:\Users\Hilal\Desktop\laravel-10\public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Hilal\Desktop\laravel-10\public\index.php on line 12

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Hilal\Desktop\laravel-10\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Hilal\Desktop\laravel-10\public\index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Hilal\Desktop\laravel-10\public\index.php on line 12*

then i deleted vendor folder and composer.lock file the installed the vendor using this command **composer install**

But still i'm not able to run the project.

Comment: Did you check whether the files in question exist? Also, why not add the zip extension, as recommended in the first error message? Finally, if this is a problem of Laravel 10, please don't tag your question with Laravel 9

Answer (score 1):

I have already encountered this error before.
Try opening the **php.ini** file first ---> **C:\xampp\php\php.ini**.
In this file, at line **962**, you can see that the line "**;extension=zip**" is commented out.
It would therefore be necessary to **remove the semicolon** for this line to be taken into account.
Once this line has been modified, you can save the file, and start the installation again by typing **composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app**.
Don't forget to delete what has already been installed without this modification.

I hope my answer will help you the best

Answer (score 0):

You could consider editing your `php.ini` file under Apache server.
Access your XAMPP GUI, In the options under Apache, click `config`.
Select the `PHP(php.ini) file`.
Use the search / find functionality or in windows, you can use CTRL + F to achieve the same.
In the search box, input `extension=zip` then search.
In the line that it is found, remove the semicolon that is before it, save and rerun your script.

It should work.